# Downgrading PHP from 5.3 version to 5.2.x on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apt, php5, ubuntu-9.10

I'm looking some some way to downgrade php from 5.3 version to 5.2.x on Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.2.10 is the version that's normally installed under Karmic, so you should just have to remove your version of 5.3 and possibly undo any changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list` that you made in order to get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the php-installation, e.g. with aptitude.

Get the sources of the required php version, compile and install it.

Answer (score 0):

check this one out http://mrkandy.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/install-php-5-2-x-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/